# Angular 4; paginator's "items per page" translation

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using material design on Angular 4. I have a table with paginator on the bottom:

[image]

Is there any way to translate "Items per page" in Angular4?

I got access to this label by

```
this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel
```

in .ts file of my component, which I put in ngOnInit()

I also have translations in i18n fo .json file, which structure is:

```
"MESSAGES_LIST_TABLE": {
      "DATE": "Date",
      "FROM": "From",
      "TO": "To",
      "MESSAGE": "Message",
      "AMOUNT": "Amount",
      "BALANCE": "Balance",
      "AVAILABLE_BALANCE": "Avail. bal",
      "ITEMS_PER_PAGE": "Items per page"
}
```

Can I somehow translate it like this?

```
this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = {{'CUSTOMER.MESSAGES_LIST_TABLE.ITEMS_PER_PAGE' | translate}}
```

Answer (score 6):

You make an Injectable extending from MatPaginatorIntl

```
@Injectable()
export class MatPaginatorIntlGerman extends MatPaginatorIntl {
    itemsPerPageLabel = 'Pro Seite: ';
    nextPageLabel = 'Nächste Seite';
    previousPageLabel = 'Vorherige Seite';

    getRangeLabel = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) => {
        return ((page * pageSize) + 1) + ' - ' + ((page * pageSize) + pageSize) + ' von ' + length;
    }
}
```

And provide it like this in your module

```
{
    provide: MatPaginatorIntl,
    useClass: forwardRef(() => MatPaginatorIntlGerman)
}
```

Comment: Do I have to put @Injectable() in my component .ts file? Somwhere under ngOnInit()?

Comment: You can have it somewhere in your component at the bottom or in a new file.

Comment: Ok, I got it, thank you. Do you have any ideas what can I do, if I want to have also translation to other language and how to implement it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the best way would be to not handcode the labels in your extended MatPaginatorIntl, but to load them via a service, depending on the current language.

Answer (score 5):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51113262/7296430

`//Atribute
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;`

`ngOnInit(){
   ...
   this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'My translation for items per page.';
   ...
}`

Comment: Instead of posting an exact answer from another question (only with less context), it would be better to flag this question as a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: Excellent and quick answer. Thanks for it

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of MatPaginatorIntl and include it in a custom provider as explained in [angular material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#MatPaginatorIntl).