# How to translate mat-paginator in Angular and select pageSizeOptions ALL

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I want translate "Items per page" in 3 languages. I use i18n for that. I can select language on the top of page
I understood [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593692/how-to-translate-mat-paginator-in-angular4#51602736) but I can not think that it can be work  I in m case. I think it can be wark, if I want translate in one language.

pageSizeOptions we can select several numbers. Is it possible to select options ALL ?

Comment: If you want to customize everything, I think it's faster to create the component from scratch.