# How to change the text in the label in pagination with MatPaginator?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-pagination

I'm using Angular Material. How can I change the text in the label in the pagination display? In particular, I want to customize the label for the page size selector.

I tried to do this, but it did not seem to work:

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" [itemsPerPageLabel]="['The amount of data displayed']" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: Provide what you want and what you get as screen shot or code @user10720571

Comment: @Aarsh I want to just change the text displayed in pagination "Items per page:" https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview

Comment: I think this answer should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57675872/7173194

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well this seems to be a problem with the mat-paginator from start, and it has been discussed [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5573), so I would like you to suggest the same with work around create one file, note that in this file we are providing the lables. this class extends magpaginator and in main file we are showing that we are using the custom class for the pagination.

called `CustomMatPaginatorIntl`

like this

```
import {MatPaginatorIntl} from '@angular/material';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CustomMatPaginatorIntl extends MatPaginatorIntl {
  constructor() {
    super();  

    this.getAndInitTranslations();
  }

  getAndInitTranslations() {

      this.itemsPerPageLabel = "test";
      this.nextPageLabel = "test";
      this.previousPageLabel = "test";
      this.changes.next();

  }

 getRangeLabel = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) =>  {
    if (length === 0 || pageSize === 0) {
      return `0 / ${length}`;
    }
    length = Math.max(length, 0);
    const startIndex = page * pageSize;
    const endIndex = startIndex < length ? Math.min(startIndex + pageSize, length) : startIndex + pageSize;
    return `${startIndex + 1} - ${endIndex} / ${length}`;
  }
}
```

and import it to the providers in main.ts file

```
 providers: [{
      provide: MatPaginatorIntl, 
      useClass: CustomMatPaginatorIntl
    }]
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqbvpq)

You can keep needed things, removed one will be used from original class

Answer (score 11):

You can also do this directly from the pagination instance. For example, if you want to add commas to the paginator label.

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true })
  paginator: MatPaginator;

  decimalPipe = new DecimalPipe(navigator.language);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'Per page';
    this.paginator._intl.getRangeLabel = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) => {
      const start = page * pageSize + 1;
      const end = (page + 1) * pageSize;
      return `${start} - ${end} of ${this.decimalPipe.transform(length)}`;
    };
  }
```

Comment: This answer works for me. I also added the numeric format to start and end lable as well. `return ${this.decimalPipe.transform(start)} - ${this.decimalPipe.transform(end)} of ${this.decimalPipe.transform(length)}`;`

Comment: This should be the answer. Simple yet effective.

Answer (score 6):

Use `childView` to access paginator in your `.ts` file as follows:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  
ngOninit() {
    this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'your custom text';
}
```

Comment: here is the error i get with this approach: `core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_intl' of undefined`

Comment: ok i solved by adding `, { static: true }` to the @ViewChild

Answer (score 5):

**MatPaginator** allows you to change paginator labels using the **MatPaginatorIntl** class.

You can translate:

- itemsPerPageLabel
- nextPageLabel
- previousPageLabel
- firstPageLabel
- lastPageLabel
- getRangeLabel

I created a **localizationService** with a **translateMatPaginator** method:

```
    translateMatPaginator(paginator: MatPaginator) {
      paginator._intl.firstPageLabel = '<custom label here>';
      paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = '<custom label here>';
      paginator._intl.lastPageLabel = '<custom label here>';
      paginator._intl.nextPageLabel = '<custom label here>';
      paginator._intl.previousPageLabel = '<custom label here>';
    }
```

You only need to inject it in your component and call:

```
    this.localizationService.translateMatPaginator(paginator);
```

Answer (score 2):

this helped me to change 'itemsPerPageLabel'

In your component:

```
import { MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material/paginator';

constructor(private paginator: MatPaginatorIntl) {
    paginator.itemsPerPageLabel = 'The amount of data displayed''; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Write a custom version of `getRangeLabel`**

This is a simple, flexible, and powerful approach and allows you to customize the full paginator text instead of just one part of it.

In your component, set up your paginator:

```
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static : false}) paginator!: MatPaginator;
```

Then assign a custom function in the `afterViewInit`:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.paginator._intl.getRangeLabel = this.getRangeDisplayText;
  }
```

Then set up a custom function to display the text you need:

```
getRangeDisplayText = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) => {
  const initialText = `Displaying users`;  // customize this line
  if (length == 0 || pageSize == 0) {
    return `${initialText} 0 of ${length}`;
  }
  length = Math.max(length, 0);
  const startIndex = page * pageSize;
  const endIndex = startIndex < length 
    ? Math.min(startIndex + pageSize, length) 
    : startIndex + pageSize;
  return `${initialText} ${startIndex + 1} to ${endIndex} of ${length}`; // customize this line
};
```

This will use whatever `pageSize` and `length` you have in your HTML or have configured in your component.

```
  <mat-paginator [length]="dataSource.total"
      [pageSize]="10"
      hidePageSize
      showFirstLastButtons>
```

If your data returns 50 recordes, this will show this text:

*Displaying users 1 to 10 of 50*