# Change pagination info text angular mat table

Tags: angular7

Im working in Angular 7 material table. There im keeping pagination and my pagination code is :

```
<mat-paginator #facePaginator [pageSize]="5" [hidePageSize]="true"></mat-paginator>
```

so im getting pagination like below :

[image]

I just want to replace text `of` with `sur` in that pagination.

I was looking for something to pass as a parameter in `<mat-paginator>` tag but there's no option for that.

So i referred https://stackoverflow.com/a/54103817/6624737 this answer and i used it.

But im getting the error below :

> StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatTable -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatTable -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!

Please share me any better idea to do this.