# Pagination on Angular Material Design - Show page numbers or remove the row count

Tags: angular6, angular-material2

[image: Pagination]

Angular 6/7, Material Design.

Since I don't have access to the total number of items the item count is irrelevant (the box in the screen shot).

How do I remove the item count completely? Or alternatively show the page I'm currently on instead of the item count?

```
<mat-paginator
    itemsPerPageLabel="Items per page"
    (page)="changePage()"
    [length]="resultsLength"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

Comment: [This answer has a lot of useful examples how to customize paginator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47594193/11275812)

Comment: Thx, that's for translations (MatPaginatorIntl) though

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Remove the range label by inserting in global CSS**

```
.mat-paginator-range-label {
    display: none;
}
```

**Insert page number instead** (of course based on your API - you might not have the page info!) by inserting in your component

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
        const list = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-paginator-range-label');
        list[0].innerHTML = 'Page: ' + this.page.toString();
}
```

and of course delete the CSS rule above!

Paginator now looks like this

[image: paginator with page indicator instead of range label]

Answer (score 3):

I just modified Johan Faerch's solution to fit more to your question.

1. Create method which has two parameters, one for matpaginator and another for list of HTMLCollectionOf

   ```
   paginatorList: HTMLCollectionOf<Element>;

   onPaginateChange(paginator: MatPaginator, list: HTMLCollectionOf<Element>) {
        setTimeout((idx) => {
            let from = (paginator.pageSize * paginator.pageIndex) + 1;

            let to = (paginator.length < paginator.pageSize * (paginator.pageIndex + 1))
                ? paginator.length
                : paginator.pageSize * (paginator.pageIndex + 1);

            let toFrom = (paginator.length == 0) ? 0 : `${from} - ${to}`;
            let pageNumber = (paginator.length == 0) ? `0 of 0` : `${paginator.pageIndex + 1} of ${paginator.getNumberOfPages()}`;
            let rows = `Page ${pageNumber} (${toFrom} of ${paginator.length})`;

            if (list.length >= 1)
                list[0].innerHTML = rows; 

        }, 0, paginator.pageIndex);
   }
   ```
2. How to call this method? you can initialize this on ngAfterViewInit()

   ```
   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.paginatorList = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-paginator-range-label');

      this.onPaginateChange(this.paginator, this.paginatorList);

      this.paginator.page.subscribe(() => { // this is page change event
        onPaginateChange(this.paginator, this.paginatorList);
      });
   }
   ```
3. Include this method in your css file(note: do not include in the main styles.css file)

   ```
   .mat-paginator-range-label {
       display: none;
   }
   ```
4. You can call `onPaginateChange(this.paginator, this.paginatorList)` functions wherever you need to change the page number details other than clicking on the navigation buttons on the mat paginator.

Result looks like this

[image]

Comment: Thx but that&#39;s pretty much the opposite of what I was trying to accomplish. You have just expanded the page information (which is already there in the default solution).
I needed to remove the information since I did NOT have access to neither the total number of pages nor the total number of items.