# Angular 9 Mat-Paginator - Translation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

How can I translate the Paginator in Angular 9?

When I add

```
paginatorRefresh() {
    setTimeout(() => this.dataSourceAma.paginator = this.paginator);
    this.dataSourceAma.sort = this.sort;
    this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'Einträge pro Seite';
    this.paginator._intl.getRangeLabel = germanRangeLabel;
    // this.loading = false;
}
```

I get an error in the console:

> ** TypeError: Cannot read property '_intl' of undefined**

Comment: A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593692/how-to-translate-mat-paginator-in-angular-4) has updated information on how to do the translation

Comment: Thx that work for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to translate mat-paginator in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593692/how-to-translate-mat-paginator-in-angular-4)

Comment: We don't mark questions as solved by adding it to the title here. If you figured out the answer yourself, you can put that as an answer (self-answering is perfectly acceptable). If somebody else's answer solved it, you can mark that as accepted. If the answer was on another question, then you should accept the duplicate suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Only two actions are required:

in your module, add:

```
providers:[
{ provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useValue: getPortuguesPaginatorIntl() }
]
```

Create a file paginator.translate.ts

```
import { MatPaginatorIntl } from "@angular/material/paginator";


const portuguesRangeLabel = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) => {
  if (length == 0 || pageSize == 0) { return `0 de ${length}`; }

  length = Math.max(length, 0);

  const startIndex = page * pageSize;

  // If the start index exceeds the list length, do not try and fix the end index to the end.
  const endIndex = startIndex < length ?
    Math.min(startIndex + pageSize, length) :
    startIndex + pageSize;

  return `${startIndex + 1} - ${endIndex} de ${length}`;
}

export function getPortuguesPaginatorIntl() {
  const paginatorIntl = new MatPaginatorIntl();
  paginatorIntl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'Items por página:';
  paginatorIntl.nextPageLabel = 'Próxima página';
  paginatorIntl.previousPageLabel = 'Página anterior';
  paginatorIntl.firstPageLabel = 'Primeira página';
  paginatorIntl.lastPageLabel = 'Ultima página';
  paginatorIntl.getRangeLabel = portuguesRangeLabel;
  return paginatorIntl;
}
```