# Angular translation : how to translate datatable search and pagination

Tags: angular, datatable, internationalization, translation, angular-i18n

I'm using datatable of jquery  to show some data, I'm using angular translation @ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1", to internationalize my app and I'm search for a way to translate datatable search and pagination area !

Comment: could you please specify which datatable library and which translation library you are using ?

Comment: question updated @Nicolas

Comment: You cannot get ngx-translate to work with jQuery DataTables. You must use DataTables language feature separately.

Comment: this may benefit you you can check it [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47594193/13521237](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47594193/13521237)